# PUT method makes Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

POST request for creating user is working fine, but when I preform PUT method on a user and change the password I'm getting `Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm`, so I'm a bit confused why is this happening, so can someone please help me overcome this.

MyUserSerializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from business_accounts.models.my_user import MyUser


class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    TODO: MyUser model Serializers
    :return: TODO
    """
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(MyUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

User Detailed APIView

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from ..serializers.my_user_serializers import MyUserSerializer
from business_accounts.models.my_user import MyUser


class UserDetailView(APIView):
    """
    User detail api view
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return MyUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override serializer's `update` method also to correctly set password for PUT request:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    TODO: MyUser model Serializers
    :return: TODO
    """
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(MyUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = super(MyUserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        if password: 
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Note [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method is using for password hasing.

Comment: sorry for the late respond, I just did this, found it in the docs, need to read it a bit more, next time.

Comment: The answer is very clean and it works successfully by taking inherit. it could not be better explained, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use hashing  algorithm.
check -> [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/)